# JSON column formatting "number" without decimal place and 1000 separator as "."

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a SharePoint list where a column contains numbers but those numbers are shown as:

**Example**:  "1,181,180" instead of "1181180" (this is what I need).

I created the list importing from excel.

How can I format this column so I can see it without decimal places and 1000 separator as "." using JSON?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Number data type**, you can remove thousand operator from column settings:

1. Go to SharePoint list
2. Click on column header/name
3. Select **Column settings**
4. Select **Edit**

[image]

It will open column settings panel in modern experience like below. If you don't see the **Use thousands separator** on panel. click on **More options**.

[image]

To remove thousands operator using JSON, use below JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: I don't see the same as you do. Please check following image:
(how can I add an image in a comment?)

Comment: You are seeing the old/classic experience column settings. In my answer, I am showing you the modern experience way.

Comment: Check updated answer to see the modern experience column settings.